# What is App store screenshot size for 6.5" display?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, screenshot

Apparently, Apple documentation can't keep up with App Store changes. Until today, the biggest (optional) display size was a 5.8-Inch Super Retina Display with a resolution of 1125 x 2436 pixels. Currently, it is a 6.5-inch display, but the resolution is nowhere to be found (docs at https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd274dd925 only mention 5.8-inch display). App store connect doesn't mention the resolution and error message "The dimensions of one or more screenshots are wrong. Learn More." redirects to docs linked above.

Comment: 6.5 - iPhone Xs Max
5.5 - iPhone 8 Plus,iPhone 7 Plus,iPhone 6s Plus
ipad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation)
ipad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation)

Answer (score 591, accepted):

The new size is 1242 × 2688 pixels.

Extra information for required sizes:

- 6.7" - iPhone 14 Pro Max
- 6.5" - iPhone 11 Pro Max, iPhone XS Max
- 5.5" - iPhone 8 Plus, iPhone 7 Plus, iPhone 6s Plus
- iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (6th generation)
- iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation) ***tip:** you can use the iPad Pro 6th generation's screenshots here too*.

Comment: But iPhone XR doesn't have such resolution (it's `828x1792`). `6.5 inch (iPhone XS Max, iPhone XR)

1242 x 2688 pixels (portrait)

2688 x 1242 pixels (landscape)` https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd274dd925

Comment: If you're using the Simulator, I found that only the iPhone XS Max gave `1242 x 2688` out of the box.

Comment: Adding to what @LordParsley said, the simulator for **Iphone 11 Pro Max** also gave `1242 x 2688` resolution

Comment: 1284x2778 - add iphone 12 pro max size

Comment: It is quite weird why don't they just put the actual sizing in Appstoreconnect? Now we need to visit this stackoverflow answer everytime we are making screenshots. Thanks Apple :/

Comment: in Xcode, there is iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation). Instead, there is 4rd generation

Comment: iPadPro 2nd & 3rd gen sims don't exist by default in the later versions of xcode (e.g. 13.2.1), but you can still create them in-app or on the command line with `xcrun` e.g.:
`xcrun simctl create "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation)" com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro--12-9-inch---2nd-generation- com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-2`
and
`xcrun simctl create "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation)" com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro--12-9-inch---3rd-generation- com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-2`

Comment: Insert here Ryan Reynolds's but why gif.

Comment: Pro-tip: create some simulators and name them the appropriate size so you don't have to look this up each time you are updating your app store preview.

Comment: This answer should include a link to Apple's official documentation of this information.

Answer (score 210):

## Latest Specifications as of Feb 5, 2024

**New:**

- iPhone 15 Pro Max
- iPhone 15 Plus
- iPhone 15 Pro
- iPhone 15
- Apple Watch Ultra 2
- Apple Watch Series 9

[image]

References:

- https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd274dd925
- https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/reference/screenshot-specifications

Comment: Glad to see someone provided a reference to that table

Comment: It's really strange that Apple doesn't provide a link to that table on the page asking for the screenshots.

Comment: New URL: https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/reference/screenshot-specifications

Comment: This would be a much better answer if it wasn't simply an image. Post text as text. Do not post pictures of text. The text in the picture can't be searched or referenced and it is harder to read.

Comment: Text won't be readable at all, it's easier to see the info in a table with images.

Comment: I only target iOS 17, how am I supposed to provide 5.5, fake it?

Answer (score 75):

For latest update, ituneconnect 6.5 inch screenshot should use Iphone Xs Max. Iphone XR screenshot doesn't match.

[image]

See the above image, that's all screen size for apple screenshot

Comment: I am puzzled by that iPhone Xr there 8|

Comment: I have thought 6.5 is iPhoneX, i spend a lot of time on it.

Comment: This answer really should include a link to Apple's documentation.

Answer (score 37):

Starting March 2019, all new apps and app updates for iPhone, including universal apps, will require iPhone XS Max screenshots. They must also be built with the new iOS 12 SDK and support the latest devices. All new apps and app updates for Apple Watch will need to be built with the watchOS 5 SDK and support Apple Watch Series 4.

[image]

Comment: This is ridiculous. We did screenshots for iPhone X recently and they are forcing us to make again only for iPhone Xs Ma and XR.

Comment: @PedroPauloAmorim luckily we don't have to also include iPhone X screenshots as well anymore. You can have iPhone X use the iPhone XS Max screenshots just like the iPhone 8 can use iPhone 8 Plus screenshots.

Comment: Their docs are wrong. It says iPhone XR is 6.5" but it is 6.1" really.

Comment: The simulator on macOS has a screenshot function. Super easy.

Answer (score 23):

I found that the easiest way to get the expected result is to open simulators on Xcode of the attached below device list  and take a screenshot of the desired screens of your app you want to show via  simulator menu on the Mac:

File > New Screen Shot (Cmnd + S)

Then upload them to App Store Connect (iTunes Connect) in the Media Manager section for the named devices below.

- 6.5 - iPhone Xs Max
- 5.5 -  iPhone 8 Plus
- iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation)

Comment: The iPhone 8 Plus works great for 5.5'' screenshots. Unfortunately, when I take screenshots with iPhone Xs Max, I get 1125 × 2436 images that are not accepted by the app store for 6.5'' screenshots.

Comment: @TomFaltesek - I found the UI initially rejected it, but once I had saved the 5.5 inch and used the Choose File option, the XS Max screenshots from the simulator worked fine.

Answer (score 15):

File > New Screen Shot (Cmnd + S)

Then upload them to App Store Connect (iTunes Connect) in the Media Manager section for the named devices below.

**6.5 - iPhone Xs Max**
**5.5 - iPhone 8 Plus,iPhone 7 Plus,iPhone 6s Plus** 
**ipad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation)**
**ipad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation)**

Comment: You saved my day

Comment: When I uploaded the Max screenshot, I got the message: *We’ll use your 6.5" display app previews and screenshots for all iPhone display sizes and localizations selected in Media Manager.* - You only need additional sizes if your app appears differently on different sizes or uses multiple languages.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to take the  **1242 × 2688 pixels**  screenshot then You need to take the screenshot of **iPhone XS Max**

Comment: When I take screenshots with iPhone Xs Max, I get 1125 × 2436 images that are not accepted by the app store for 6.5'' screenshots.

Comment: We have the same issue and still confused. Trying manual update of dimension

Answer (score 9):

For 6.5" Screenshot size

**Portrait**

1242 × 2688 pixels

**Landscape**

2688 x 1242 pixels

- 6.5" - iPhone Xs Max
- 5.5" - iPhone 8 Plus,iPhone 7 Plus,iPhone 6s Plus
- ipad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation)
- ipad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation)

Answer (score 7):

the 6.5inch (1242 × 2688px) is now iPhone 11 Pro Max in the simulator!

Comment: iPhone 11 not working for me, but iPhone Pro Max does

Answer (score 6):

You can follow [iOS Human Interface Guideline](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/foundations/layout/#platform-considerations) when a new iPhone is annnounced.
The documents are usually updated soon after the announcement.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using **iPhone XR** with 6.1'' display, you can use Mac's built-in preview tool to resize to 150% then you will be able to upload.

Answer (score 3):

Apple updates the specifications inline with new hardware rollouts. Most of the information on this page is out of date.

The best answer is to check [Apple's Screenshot specifications page](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd274dd925).

Answer (score 2):

**AS OF 2023-02-20**

https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/reference/screenshot-specifications

App Store Connect screenshot specifications are now in App Store Connect developer reference.

Answer (score 1):

The new size is 1290 × 2796 pixels

Information for required sizes:

> New size for iPhone Simulator or Device

- 6.7" - iPhone 14 Pro Max
- 6.5" - iPhone 11 Pro Max, iPhone Xs Max
- 5.5" - iPhone 8 Plus, iPhone 7 Plus, iPhone 6s Plus
- 12.9" - iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (6th generation)
- 12.9" - iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation)

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/reference/screenshot-specifications
[enter link description here](https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/reference/screenshot-specifications)

6.5" Display

iPhone 14 Plus

iPhone 13 Pro Max

iPhone 12 Pro Max

iPhone 11 Pro Max

iPhone 11

iPhone XS Max

iPhone XR

Comment: It seems that you provide nothing beyond what is already given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62664030/7733418 That you invested the effort to type in the device names (appreciated for accessability) could have been an edit on that post.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34947253)