# What simulator do I have to use for taking the screenshot for the Apple Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm trying to publish my app in the Apple Store and same screenshots are required. Based on the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/reference/screenshot-specifications), I created the required screenshots.

The screenshots for *iPhone 6.7" Display* are from the *iPhone 15 Pro Max* and it is ok for the Apple Store. The problem is with the other required screenshots. I tried a lot fo other devices but none of them has the pixel size that is required.

For example, for the *5.5" Display* (1242 x 2208px) based on the documentation, I have to use *iPhone 8 Plus* but the screenshot doesn't have the right size (1125 × 2436).

[image]

I saw some other posts (for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56141725/what-simulator-devices-are-currently-needed-to-make-screenshots-for-apple-app-st) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52310183/what-is-app-store-screenshot-size-for-6-5-display)) but the reference is to the Apple documentation that is not right.

Comment: I ran the iPhone 8 Plus simulator just now and the screenshot size I got was 1242 x 2208. What version of iOS and Xcode are you using?

Comment: The latest one, just updated them but iPhone 8 Plus doesn't have this size

Comment: Could you specify the actual versions please?

Comment: XCode 15.2 (15C500b) - Simulator Version 15.2 (1019), CoreSimulator 944.5

Comment: What version of iOS?

Comment: The iOS is 17.0

Comment: The iPhone 8 Plus is [not compatible with iOS 17](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/iphone/iphe3fa5df43/ios). Can't run the Simulator on an iPhone 8 Plus in iOS 17. Double check in the SImulator which device/version you are actually running.